# I can't find format file latex.fmt

Tags: texlive, debian

I recently removed (most of) my installation of latex due to problems with the hyperref package. I reinstalled texlive using

```
sudo apt-get texlive texlive-latex-extra
```

which gave these messages (among other things):

```
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... 
updmap-sys failed. Output has been stored in
/tmp/updmap.nxBASPom
Please include this file if you report a bug.

Sometimes, not accepting conffile updates in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
causes updmap-sys to fail.  Please check for files with extension
.dpkg-dist or .ucf-dist in this directory

dpkg: errors under treatment of tex-common (--configure):
under proces installed post-installation-script returned final stragegies 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I can't run latex anymore. It gives the following answer:

```
kpathsea: Running mktefmt latex.fmt
I can't find the format file 'latex.fmt'!
```

I dont understand what is wrong. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Sounds like you need to reinstall the base parts of the distribution `texlive-latex-base` etc.  See e.g. http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html

Comment: Please *read* what was written over there ....updmap-sys failed. Output has been stored in
/tmp/updmap.nxBASPom
Please include this file if you report a bug. You should show this file. Did you do a new installation of the whole TeX system, what are you running? sid? testing? stable? ...

Comment: Ok! I am affraid that updmap-sys dint't say me much. I installed texlive2012 using directions on the internet. Now it works.